# Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error

Tags: runtime-error, double-submit-problem

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

How to **fix** this problem? And what does Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error mean?

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlHelperLinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_HtmlHelperLinkExtensions_ActionLink_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_)
This link will help you with the different types of overload function of Actionlink.

The problem occurs because you are not routing your request to the correct contoller, in case of ASP.net. If the query still persist then please elaborate your issue.